# Should I install Gentoo i586 packages on my PC?

Tags: cpu, intel, x86, linux, hp

I've recently commenced revitalizing an [HP Pavilion Slim](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03791266). She's running an Intel Pentium, x86_64. I thought I'd give Gentoo a go because I've found it very appealing and as a Bedrock user I wanted to be able to boot off of Gentoo's init system (initrc, we all know why) as well as bootloader. I've gotten almost halfway through the install ( maybe more like a third :))) ), and now I'm looking for the `stage3` files for my PC. I've noticed that though there are builds for `i486` and `i686`. Being genuinely interested in which my PC was, I searched it up and after some light digging found this explanation:

> - i386 works with any x86 processor (Intel, AMD,etc.),
> - i486 has some performance tun[n]ing.
> - i586 for Pentium and Pentium-MMX
> - i686 for Pentium-Pro, P2,P3, P4, etc.

[[source]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-i486-i686-410580/#post2081265)

But in that case Gentoo doesn't support my device?!? Hence, my question: what `i` version (?) is my Intel Pentium PC? And where are the `stage3` files for it? Is it possible to use, say, an `i486` for a presumed `i586`?

Comment: "Very old"? Look at the on topic questions on this site, then you will know what is "very old" 

Comment: The machine linked is less than 7 years old, as G2020 was introduced in 2013. It features an up to date AMD64 ISA, way beyond everything mentioned and capable to run any modern version of any OS. You might rather want to ask in [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: This belongs to the Unix & Linux SE site

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know, I posted it there originally - that's when someone told me to go here...

Comment: @Bobbbay Are you okay for this question to be migrated to [unix.se]?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The problem is, it's already there - but apart from that, I would be fine with it!

Comment: @Bobbbay Unfortunately, the question is too old for the system to let me migrate. ☹ It _should_ be there, though, and it's got good answers; apart from being off-topic, it's a good question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 :( well, that sucks. Let me know if you need anything - I could delete the question, but I'm glad you like that it's good :).

Comment: @Bobbbay You can't delete the question, because it has answers.

Comment: Duly noted! In that case, I just assume it's stuck in the never-ending abyss of retrocomputing... ;)

Answer (score 9):

The original Pentium, which succeeded the i80486, was indeed the original definition of the i586 instruction set - and *not* x86_64.  But the Pentium was introduced in 1993, and your HP machine is *much* newer than that.  Intel has continued to use the Pentium brand for almost every x86-compatible CPU line they've made since then, to great confusion among people not intimately familiar with the history.

As a brief summary:

- 8088, 8086, 80286, 80386, 80486 are all pre-Pentium
- Pentium Classic (aka P5, defined i586)
- Pentium MMX
- Pentium Pro (aka P6, defined i686)
- Pentium II
- Pentium III (introduced SSE)
- Pentium 4 (aka NetBurst, introduced SSE2)
- Pentium M (for laptops)
- Core series, which itself has gone through many versions.

Since the Core series was introduced, Intel now uses the Pentium and Celeron branding for low-end and often severely cut-down versions of Core series processors.

The Pentium G-series is one of these cut-down Core series CPUs, does support x86_64, and is really too new to ask the Retrocomputing SE about.  I will simply recommend you to install the `amd64` version of Gentoo rather than the `i586` or `i686` builds.

For anyone who actually has a Pentium Classic, Pentium-MMX, or other genuine i586 device, Gentoo doesn't have an i586 stage build, but the i486 build will work.  You can then rebuild it optimised for i586 and the specific CPU that you have.  Expect it to take some time, on the order of weeks, as these CPUs are very old and slow.

Comment: Ah. Well, thanks, but that sucks for me :))) I already used the x86 "minimal" ISO for my boot USB. I'm guessing I'd have to completely redo with the different ISO? Or could I continue on but using the `amd64` `stage3` files? Thanks!

Comment: @Bobbay The `amd64` userspace requires both an `amd64` CPU and an `amd64` kernel.  However, you should be able to use the same disk partitions and filesystem format.

Comment: I don't think that blindly installing amd64 is *always* a good idea. For memory-limited systems i386 is definitely less memory-hungry, Also there exist programs that *do* work faster in i386 flavour than in amd64.

Comment: @lvd It's unlikely to have less than 1GB installed, which is what I'd call "memory limited".  The OP clearly doesn't have any niche use case in mind, or they'd have done more research beforehand.  A 64-bit OS is always a good match for 64-bit hardware, *especially* in the case of AMD64 versus x86.

Comment: _"Expect it to take some time"_ True. Then again [distcc](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc) is a great help to those emerging/compiling stuff for slower processors. It is well integrated with the Gentoo build process and can be used early on. So booting the premade i486 and optimize later on isn't much differnt from doing so on the fastest machine one owns.

Comment: @Raffzahn, if GCC can be compiled through `distcc`, I haven't figured out how, and in my experience, it's GCC that's the most resource-intensive thing to compile on a typical i586.  (My Pentium MMX looks like it'll be stuck on GCC 6.4.0: that took two months to compile, and takes up 10% of the available disk space.)

Comment: Are you okay for this question to be migrated to [unix.se]?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Seems fair.

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo is a source-based distribution, where everything is built from the source. You can tune GCC to build for i586 like this:

```
COMMON_FLAGS="-march=i586 -mtune=pentium -O2 -pipe"
```

in your /etc/portage/make.conf

Changing `-O2` to `-Os` will decrease executables size a bit.

Another thing you need to worry is to build correct kernel.

If the build process is failing or slow on your device, you can try building everything in a virtual machine on a modern pc, then transfer image to the device.

To know what CPU you do have, find any bootable 'live' linux distribution (that is able to boot on your old pc, this for example http://tinycorelinux.net/) and then type `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. You can try to use this tiny linux as a chroot base system for your gentoo, as well.

Comment: Are you okay for this question to be migrated to [unix.se]?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that's ok